# Elastic Search - How to query Array of JSON objects?

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, query-builder, spring-data-elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

I have a data available in ES in the below format. Lets call each json object as campaign object.

```
{id:"c1", tags:[{key:"k1",value:"v1"}, {key:"k2",value:"v2"}, {key:"k3",value:"v3"}]}

{id:"c2", tags:[{key:"k1",value:"v1"}, {key:"k4",value:"v4"}]}

{id:"c3", tags:[{key:"k5",value:"v5"}, {key:"k2",value:"v2"}]}
```

My client sends me the list of tag objects, i have to return the corresponding campaign objects to the client.
For ex.
1st Example
Req. -

```
[{key:"k1",value:"v1"}]
```

Res. -

```
{id:"c1", tags:[{key:"k1",value:"v1"}, {key:"k2",value:"v2"}, {key:"k3",value:"v3"}]}

{id:"c2", tags:[{key:"k1",value:"v1"}, {key:"k4",value:"v4"}]}
```

2nd Example
Req. -

```
[{key:"k3",value:"v3"},{key:"k5",value:"v5"}]
```

Res. -

```
{id:"c2", tags:[{key:"k1",value:"v1"}, {key:"k4",value:"v4"}]}

{id:"c3", tags:[{key:"k5",value:"v5"}, {key:"k2",value:"v2"}]}
```

My service is written in spring boot, which es querybuilder(termsquery,nestedquery) should i use to achieve the same?

I tried this sample query , but it is returning empty list.

boolQueryBuilder.filter(
QueryBuilders.termsQuery("tags", TAG_LIST));

Comment: if field tags is nested type you must use nested query.

Comment: which versions of Spring Boot, Spring Data Elasticsearch  and Elasticsearch are you using?

Answer (score 0):

If Tags is Nested try this:

```
    var query = QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
        .must(QueryBuilders.termsQuery("tags.key", "k1"))
        .must(QueryBuilders.termsQuery("tags.value", "v1"));
    var nestedQuery = QueryBuilders
        .nestedQuery("tags", query, ScoreMode.None);

    SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest();
    SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
    searchSourceBuilder.query(nestedQuery);
    searchRequest.indices("idx_test");
    searchRequest.source(searchSourceBuilder);
```